# Tikz anchor for nodes are not set?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem just getting started with TikZ.
I want to use it in `beamer` but I have the same problem with minimal so I just give the `beamer` test.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\tikz\node (A){$A$};\hspace{1cm}
\tikz\node (B){$B$};\hspace{1cm}
\tikz\node (C){$C$};
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[<->] (A) -- (B);
       \draw[<->] (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image: result]

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the scope of node names is (roughly speaking) the surrounding `tikzpicture`, so when you issue the `\draw` commands the names are not attached to any entity. There is no need to space the nodes outside the `tikzpicture` as you can directly do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node (A){$A$};
       \node (B) at (1,0) {$B$};
       \node (C) at (2,0) {$C$};
       \draw[<->] (A) -- (B);
       \draw[<->] (B) -- (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are cases where you need to reference names outside the picture and that's what the option `remember picture` is for (see Section 16.13 of the manual).

Comment: great, thanks!Was it different in previous versions?